# Wordpress: Advanced Custom Fields: Exporting and Importing

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created two custom field groups in a temporary WordPress install and would now like to use the export of them to import them into a new WordPress install, however, on my local server I set the page to home which is where I want the users to be able to edit the page user ACF. After importing to my live server, values were set automatically to blog instead of home any idea how to fix this.[image: what i want it to show on my live server after importing]

[image: what its currently showing after importing the ACF]

Kindly advise me how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Advanced Custom Fields will apply the rule you've setup, to show the fields on home, based on the ID of that page.

On your local installation, home will have one ID. On another installation that ID may be allocated to a different page entirely. That's the issue you're seeing here.

If you view the JSON file that's generated when you export fields you'll come across the following:

```
"location": [
        [
            {
                "param": "page",
                "operator": "==",
                "value": "5"
            }
        ]
  ],
```

In the example above `"value"` could be any number and it represents the ID of the page, "Home". If you know the value of the page, "Home", where you're importing this content you can update it.

With that in mind the benefit is quite limited. You need to know the ID in advance and if you've already anticipated the problem it becomes just as easy to correct once the import is complete.

Comment: thanks. However, what other way do you think I can use as I don't want users to see the custom fields plugin. I only want them to play around with what is set in the application.

Comment: That's a different question entirely. Use capabilities to handle display of the ACF menu item

Comment: Okay cool. However, how about if you use the page templates do you think that will solve the problem

Comment: If the site you're exporting from uses the same theme/templates as the site you're importing into then that would work fine.

Comment: thanks however, it still did not work. However, i managed to add  this line of code in functions.photo define('ACF_LITE', true); include_once('advanced-custom-fields/acf.php'); which kind of hide the custom fields from users.